# How to send getJSON a string with special characters?

Tags: javascript, java, json, encoding, utf8-decode

I want to send a getJSON with special characters?
In this case i have a .js file which create the string to send using getJSON methos. for that i use following command.

```
$.getJSON(strUrl, UI_DesignPecTab.validateResponse);
```

Using above method i need to send a string like follows :

```
var ID = "W6"
var headerString = "PT##?" + ID + "Z#@;#TKT/#CHK/#BOR/";
```

But when i send this to server side it fails due to this uri contains some invalid characters? I need to know how can i get this done. I have tried to encode and send this using "encodeURIComponent()" but um not sure is it correct or not? if it correct how to decode it server side in java? For the above method i have used following code:

```
headString = URLDecoder.decode(pecTabData.getHeadString(), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: try URLEncoder.encode to encode... URLDecoder.decode to decode

Comment: How are you sending the json string? Is it part of the URL or is it a POST parameter?

Comment: Use UTF8 Encoding type

Comment: I used "encodeURIComponent(strUrl)" this to encode but it does not seems to work.